# How to access data injected by interceptor inside nestjs services?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, interceptor

I'm working with a NestJS Interceptor that handles [GolevelUP/Rabbitmq](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq) transactions. I created an interceptor to inject some data and perform some calculations. In my case, I need to access the injected data inside some service calls.

Here is a code snippet to illustrate my scenario:

```js
//interceptor.ts

const data = <....anything....>
```

```js
//service.ts
this.serviceInjected1.someCall()
return this.serviceInjected2.someCall()
```

My question is, how can I access data inside serviceInjected1() and serviceInjected2()? I tried using request scope for providers, but it is not working as expected.

I would appreciate any help or guidance on how to achieve this. Thank you.